# Java split and add elements into corrsponding data type arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist, split

My problem is when a user enters text it should have two elements to split when using .split() however with the items it splits how do I put them into different lists so that I can use integer based list to make calculations.

e.g.
a user enters "skyrim , 100" the 'skyrim' entry is a string however with the number (integer) '100' I want to split it removing the comma and add it to a ArrayList for calculations and with other inputs added.

game name(String) , hours(integers) <- template

1. skyrim , 100
2. oblivion , 25
3. GTA V , 50

so the listed items above are user input with 2 arguments separated by a comma, which will be split, then I need to add them to different arraylists.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

Arraylist<String> game = new Arraylist<>();
Arraylist<Integer> hours = new Arraylist<>();
Arraylist<Object> allGameData = new Arraylist<>();

String gameEntry = input.nextLine().split(" , ");

allGameData.add(gameEntry);

foreach(object items : allGameData) { 
System.out.println(items);
}
```

so from here I should have:

skyrim , 100 , oblivion, 25, GTAV , 50

How do i put the game names into the game list and the numbers into the hours list?

Comment: On each line, is the first entry always going to be a `String`, and the second always going to be an `int`? In your example this seems to be the case. [skyrim , 100] [oblivion , 25] [gtav , 50]

Comment: yeah exactly that, String then int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for starters, the class you should be using is `ArrayList` with a capital *L*. So you need to change:

```
Arraylist<String> game = new Arraylist<>();
Arraylist<Integer> hours = new Arraylist<>();
Arraylist<Object> allGameData = new Arraylist<>();
```

to this:

```
ArrayList<String> game = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> hours = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Object> allGameData = new ArrayList<>();
```

After we have them initialized correctly we add to the `ArrayList` with `#.add` so in your case you would add to the `game` and `hours` list like:

```
game.add("some game");
hours.add(10);
```

When you split your input with `input.nextLine().split(" , ");` we are expecting a String array to be returned. Currently you are trying to set this to just a String instead of a String array.

```
while (true){
    System.out.println("Enter \"game , hours\" or \"Quit\"");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    if (line.equals("Quit")) break;
    allGameData.add(line);
    String[] parsedData = line.split(" , ");
    game.add(parsedData[0]);
    hours.add(Integer.parseInt(parsedData[1]));
}
```

Comment: but how would 'game' and 'hours' add elements from 'allGameData' since I am using that arrayList to add elements from user input and split it so that it can be put into 'game and 'hours' wouldn't I need to reference elements from allGameData?

Comment: @Aetherox I would not split the string until you add it to your `allGameData` list. Then split and add to `game` and `hours`. Let me update the solution to give better context.

Comment: can that small solution be used with a loop to get more entries, split it and then put into the corresponding arraylists so Im not writing game.add(parsedData[0]);
hours.add(Integer.parseInt(parsedData[1])); over and over for more elements being added

Comment: @Aetherox yup already put it in a loop. See new update. Essentially it will keep on looping until the user enters _Quit_. You should also add some user input validation.

Comment: yeah im just getting functionality down before validation

Comment: Thanks this helped and covered what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Integer.parseInt()`.  The code you submitted looks pseudo-codey, but this is something like what You're going for:

```
String gameEntry = input.nextLine();
allGameData.add(gameEntry);
String[] splitGameEntry = input.nextLine().split(" , ");
game.add(splitGameEntry[0]);
hours.add(Integer.parseInt(splitGameEntry[1]));
```

I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish with this code, but you may want to organize the game/hours into a class that holds both values.  Your code would then look something like this:

```
public class GameInfo
{
    private String name;
    private int hours;

    public GameInfo(String name, int hours)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    [getters/setters]

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name + ":  " + hours + " hours played!";
    }
}

public class Main
{

    public void doSomething()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<GameInfo> gameInfo = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] gameEntry = input.nextLint().split(" , ");

        gameInfo.add(new GameInfo(gameEntry[0], Integer.parseInt(gameEntry[1]));

        for(GameInfo gameInfoPiece : gameInfo)
        {
            System.out.println(gameInfoPiece);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this approach, you would be able to add as much information into the `GameInfo` class as you want.  For instance, if you wanted to change `hours` to `expectedHoursToComplete` and add `actualHoursToComplete`, you could easily do that.

Comment: how would I do that with multiple entries of input without having to write add(gameentry[0]) then add(gameEntry[2]) everytime a user enters something because it will go up in 2's for string elements?

Comment: @Aetherox do you want just a single entry in allGameData per each line submitted by the user?

Comment: yeah a single entry per each line so I enter 'skyrim , 100' then possibly add more entries then split them and put them into different arraylists.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier if you rethink your approach. Rather than have 3 separate lists why not store it all in a single `Map<String,Integer>` where the key is the game name and the value is the number of hours.

Your code would look something like the following:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    Map<String, Integer> gameHoursMap = new HashMap<>();

    String currentValue = scan.nextLine();

    // Loop until you meet some criteria to end such as typing q or quit
    while(!currentValue.equalsIgnoreCase("q")){

        // You would need to handle when the value of currentValue doesn't fit what you would normally be expecting before doing the rest
        String[] vals = currentValue.split(",");

        // Call trim method on the String incase there is any lingering whitespace
        gameHoursMap.put(vals[0].trim(), Integer.valueOf(vals[1].trim()));

        currentValue = scan.nextLine();
    }
```

You would obviously need to write some error handling for when the input doesn't fit with what you're expecting but you get the gist.

UPDATE:

If you wanted to have more complicated info stored for each game you could wrap it up in a custom class `GameInfo` and then have a `Map<String,GameInfo>` where the key is the name and the value is the `GameInfo`. This would allow you to retrieve all of the game info for a game just based on the name.

```
public class GameInfo {

   private String name;
   private int hoursPlayed;
   private int level;

   // etc
}
```

You would then amend the `while` loop to create the `GameInfo` object instead of just putting a `String` and `int` into the `Map`

```
// Create the GameInfo object from the corresponding input supplied by the user
GameInfo game = new GameInfo(vals[0].trim(), Integer.valueOf(vals[1].trim()), Integer.valueOf(vals[2].trim()));

// Put it in the map with the name as the key
gameMap.put(game.getName(), game);
```

Comment: Could i increase that map to take more data types e.g. map<String, Integer, integer>

Comment: I will update my answer to explain what you could do...you can't do what you have just written `map<String, Integer, integer>` as a map can only have a key-value pair